# Error while accessing webservice

Tags: web-services

i have created a web service, which i accessed through a test application, it works fine with out throwing any exception.

But while client accessing the same web service, they are able to get the output but they are also getting an exception saying

`Unable to automatically step into server.connecting to the server machine'xxxxxx' failed.Logon failure: unknown username and password`

i have also attached the screen shot , where our client access the API[webservice]
& then get an exception error.

Answer (score 0):

Without a mention of what web platform and langugage you're using, its difficult to be specific.

But, judging by the error message `unknown username and password` I would guess that you have one of these issues:

- the wrong credentials at the client.
- A web server configuration that requires login for your client, but not for your test application.

Do you run the test application on the server, or on a remote machine? What happens if you run the test application on the clients machine?